# Promoting a staging repository

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

Is there a safe and easy way of pushing a staging repository created by `mvn release:staging` to the real deployment repository that does not depend on  a commercial version of any given repository manager?

Comment: I think that this can help you http://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/adminguide/staging-repositories.html

Comment: I don't see how that helps - I need a solution that does not depend on Archiva or any other repository manager.